# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence when array is not a sequence

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Hello this code  is intended to store the coordinates of rectangles drawn with open cv and compile the results into a single image.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
im3 = im.copy()

gray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,1,1,11,2)



contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


squares = []

for cnt in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(cnt)>50:
        [x,y,w,h] = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)

        if  h>28 and h<34:
            rect = (cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,255),3))
            squares.append(cv2.boundingRect(cnt))
            cv2.imwrite('norm1.jpg',im)

crop_img = [[255 for x in xrange(377)] for x in xrange(377) ]

for s in squares:
    s = squares[0]
    x = s[0]
    y = s[1]
    w = s[2]
    h = s[3]
    img = im[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    for col in range(y,y+h):
        for row in range(x,x+w):
            if img[col - y][row - x].tolist() == [0,0,0]:
                crop_img[col][row] = [0,0,0]



cv2.imwrite("cropped.jpg", np.array(crop_img))
```

However, it throws this error message

```
File "C:\Users\Program\Desktop\new  1.py", line 43, in <module>
    cv2.imwrite("cropped.jpg", np.array(crop_img))
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

I have read that this can be caused by an "uneven" matrix but after several rounds of testing I have confirmed that it is indeed a square **377 x 377 matrix**

For reference: "1.jpg" is the image shown below

[image: 1]

Any leads as to how to fix this error would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each "pixel" here have one value. `crop_img = [[255 for x in xrange(377)] for x in xrange(377) ]`

But later you're setting some of them to a list of 3 values. That's the problem.
This should fix it i think:
`crop_img = [[[255, 255, 255] for x in xrange(377)] for x in xrange(377) ]`

Although you might as well start off with a numpy array with shape 377,377, 3 instead of converting it afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It allowed me to fix the problem but the final image i'm getting from "cropped.jpg" is showing a large amount of pixel loss as shown in this picture. http://i622.photobucket.com/albums/tt310/seraphelitis/cropped_zpse1671541.jpg any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: How does the image look after thresholding? Probably not all of the pixels have the value 0,0,0 after that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is what the image looks like after final thresholding http://i622.photobucket.com/albums/tt310/seraphelitis/cropped3_zps0b1fd569.jpg. you can find my whole code here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153466/letters-blurry-fuzzy-after-crop-function. Thanks so much for the help

Comment: That image have some values beside 0 and 255. Simply do `np.unique(thresh)` to see them. You might wanna try another threshold function that set's the value to either 0 or 255.

Comment: Sorry but what would you suggest for an alternative thresholding function that achieves the same effect?

Comment: Binary thresholding from here http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#threshold

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45362/discussion-between-jamesllee-and-m4rtini)

Answer (score 2):

```
                crop_img[col][row] = [0,0,0]
```

Is this supposed to be an RGB value? `crop_img` starts as a list of 377 elements, each of which is a list of 377 elements, each element of which is the integer `255`. This line replaces a `255` with a list. It's not clear whether you want 2-dimensional nesting, which is the way you're initializing `crop_img`, or 3-dimensional nesting, which is what this line would suggest. Pick the one that's correct for your application and stick with it.