# Letters blurry / fuzzy after crop function

Tags: python, opencv, crop

after attempting to crop my image in several locations by saving the list of coordinates to an array the letters in the cropped area become extremely blurry and I cannot figure out why.

The original image looks like

[image: 1]

After cropping the image looks like

[image: 2]

The code in questions is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

im2 = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
im = im2.copy()

gray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,1,1,11,2)


contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


squares = []

for cnt in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(cnt)>50:
        [x,y,w,h] = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)

        if  h>28 and h<34:
            rect = (cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,255),3))
            squares.append(cv2.boundingRect(cnt))
            cv2.imwrite('norm1.jpg',im)

crop_img = [[[255, 255, 255] for x in xrange(377)] for x in xrange(377) ]

for s in squares:
    x = s[0]
    y = s[1]
    w = s[2]
    h = s[3]
    img = im[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    for col in range(y,y+h):
        for row in range(x,x+w):
            if img[col - y][row - x].tolist() == [0,0,0]:
                crop_img[col][row] = [0,0,0]
cv2.imwrite("cropped.jpg", np.array(crop_img))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In your code, which variable is first and which variable is second. Also I am not sure, but Check if your data type is changed somewhere.

Comment: Hi Abid. I'm not sure what you mean by "first and second" but I know that my data type is changed in the line "if img[col - y][row - x].tolist() == [0,0,0]:" I had to use the .tolist function because it was throwing the error: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

I hope this clears some of it up. Thanks!

Comment: Oh... I am sorry, I wanted to ask "In your code, which variable is first image in your question and which variable is second image".

Comment: that's ok! "norm1.jpg" in my code would be the first image and "cropped.jpg" would be my second image @AbidRahmanK

Comment: Running your code in my system, For cropped.jpg, I get a full white image. Nothing else. Is it the expected result?

Comment: thanks for being so patient. please use
http://i622.photobucket.com/albums/tt310/seraphelitis/1_zpsdff7b73a.jpg as your input image that i have labeled "1.jpg" in my code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45345/discussion-between-jamesllee-and-abid-rahman-k)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im2 = cv2.imread('norm1_zps89266edb.jpg')
im = im2.copy()

gray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
ret3,thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

#we ony want the external contours
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 
#extract the countours with area > 50
squares = [cnt for cnt in contours if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 50]

#mask array with the same shape as img (but only 1 channel)
mask = np.zeros((im.shape[0], im.shape[1]))
#draw the contours filled with 255 values. 
cv2.drawContours(mask,squares,-1,255,-1)

newImage = np.where(mask==255, thresh, 255)

plt.imshow(newImage)
plt.show()

cv2.imwrite("cropped.jpg", newImage)
```

output:
[image: http://i44.tinypic.com/8yak93.jpg]