# Change plt.imshow() into cv2.imshow() in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I have python code like below.

```
def konvolusi(self, X, F):
    X_height = X.shape[0]
    X_width = X.shape[1]
    F_height = F.shape[0]
    F_width = F.shape[1]
    H = (F_height) // 2
    W = (F_width) // 2
    out = np.zeros((X_height, X_width))
    for i in np.arange(H+1, X_height - H):
        for j in np.arange(W+1, X_width - W):
            sum = 0
            for k in np.arange(-H, H+1):
                for l in np.arange(-W, W+1):
                    a = X[i+k, j+l]
                    w = F[H+k, W+l]
                    sum += (w*a)
                out[i,j] = sum
    return out

def gaussianBlur(self):
    img1 = self.image
    gaussian = (1.0 / 345) * np.array(
        [[1, 5, 7, 5, 1],
        [5, 20, 33, 20, 5],
        [7, 33, 55, 33, 7],
        [5, 20, 33, 20,5],
        [1, 5, 7, 5, 1]])
    img = self.konvolusi(img1, gaussian)
    self.image = img;
    plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray', interpolation='bicubic')
    plt.xticks([], plt.yticks([]))
    plt.show()
```

in def `gaussianBlur()`, the img variable is displayed using the `plt.imshow()` function, how do I display the img variable with the `cv2.imshow()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import cv2

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: ya, of course I have imported the cv2 library, the code above is just a snippet, I've tried using the cv2.imshow function on the "img" variable but the program immediately gets an error

Comment: idk, program didn't show up, and there is no error log

Comment: oh wait, this is the error "setting an array element with a sequence." just that, i dont understand

Comment: please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133214/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-when-array-is-not-a-sequenc